# Schematic symbols

Tags: symbol

What is that red symbol on the schematic?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I would say that is a group of solder pads that are used as jumpers - short the center and top pads with a blob of solder to select one function, and bottom and center for the other.

Comment: It is indeed a 3-way Surface-Mount (SMD) jumper. I used these A LOT for physical debugging purposes

Comment: Isn't something like that tool, or company dependent?

Comment: @SteveSh: Yes.  Both the schematic symbol and pcb footprint may vary between designers, or even between jobs for a given designer.

Comment: +1 In this case, it might be used for address selection for an I2C peripheral.